# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method (JsonSerializer)

Tags: java, abstract-class

Trying to override the JsonSerializer.serialize method, But I'm getting a `CommandSerializer is not abstract and does not override abstract method serialize(Command,Type,JsonSerializationContext) in JsonSerializer`

I need to instantiate the `CommandSerializer` later on so I cannot make this an abstract class. Am I missing something, anywhere else I shoudl look? Here is my code:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public interface Command extends DeviceCommand {

    public static class CommandSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Command> {
        public JsonElement serialize(Command command, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(command.toString());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

JsonSerializer looks like this:

```
public interface JsonSerializer<T> {
  public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context);
}
```

Comment: Strange. Just to be sure, maybe you want to put `@Override" on that method.

Comment: Do your import statements line up? My first guess is that "Type" may be coming from a different package.